# Excel: Having 3 values in a range of cells High, Medium, Poor. How to change them into integers like 1,2,3 as placeholder?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Edit after the kind indication from Scott Craner how to state this right. sorry for the inconvenience and wasted time of yours

[image]

The Formula in F2 gets the Value of another Sheet where the Text High, Medium or Poor is saved as plain text. Now i would like to replace this texts with numbers so it is easier to calculate with it and to save it into a DB.
I found the Formula:

```
=SWITCH(F2,"High",3,"Medium",2,"Poor",1)
```

in my understanding this should do what I'm trying to but my excel version 2016 does not have this function. Furtheremore, there is no update button to update my excel. Any suggestions how to solve this Problem?

The Formula i use in F2 to get the value from another table is:

```
=VLOOKUP("Quality",INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&V2),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: And how are you determining what's high/medium/poor?

Comment: the terms high, medium and poor are defined in another table. I was just wondering if there is a simpler formula than a double if statement. Something like Switch Case as it is used in PHP

Comment: What is the formula?

Comment: @J. Doe We can't determine that for you without seeing your current formula.

Comment: There are any number of functions that can handle that situation: Any of the several `LOOKUP` functions. Also `SWITCH`, `IFS`, combinations of `INDEX/MATCH`, `CHOOSE`, etc.  Suggest you research and edit your question if you run into a problem (or delete it if you don't).

Comment: That is my question, what is the formula, to replace high, medium and low with 1,2,3 i don't have a proper formula for that scenario except of: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("VMI with suppliers",purchasing!A2:C16,2,FALSE)),"NULL",IF(G2="no",0,1))

Comment: this downvotes reminds me on the guy who said look it up on google. funny thing about that was, that it was the first suggestion on google! No need to bully other people who have serious questions! Why not just give the answer several times? obviously i couldn't find it with the help of google before and that's why I'm asking here! This culture of rather giving a unkind comment than just ignore it or give an answer is poison for the internet of free information for everyone

Comment: Nobody is bullying you. I didn't downvote, but check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You've taken the tour, so you know to post what you've tried so far. You did, but it's in the comments.  This seems like a relatively easy solution, check in to `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX/MATCH` or of course the simple `Find/Replace`. There are myriad ways to replace specific text with other text, you should have no problem finding a solution already posted here on SO, and of course via Google generally.  There are also, IMO, no unkind comments here, no need to get defensive.

Comment: You're looking to find something similar to Switch case in PHP? A cursory Google search will tell you, yes, VBA has `Select Case`.  In your OP you also don't clarify fully how the high/medium/poor are being determined...There's data missing that would help us help you.

Comment: Yeah, I'll need it as a formula tough

Comment: Simple question how do i change the Text "High", "Medium", "Poor" into 3,2,1 Numbers so i can do further calculations with it. No need to know where the text is from! A simple Answer would have been enough thanks, over and out.

Comment: @J.Doe we need to know how you are populating the High,Medium,Poor.  Because we need to help you modify that formula if you want us to do it in place.  if you do not want to do the change in place then you can use many different formula to do that, we need to know, are you open to using helper columns or not. if you want to make the changes in place, Depending on how you are populating the cell, will determine what is the best formula to use.  There are a myriad of methods and it all depends on what the starting point is.

Comment: @Scott Carner, thank you for your kind explanation, on what went wrong. after all this comments i just got angry, because i think this community should be about helping each other to get better in every way instead of just blaming someone for not asking or answering correctly. And if there is anything missing i would appreciate it if someone would just say that instead of asking for a formula when i said i was looking for one.

Comment: Excel 2016 does have the `SWITCH` function, I just used it.

Comment: @ashleedawgh some excel 2016 versions have it yes, that's right. Some say it helps to update the version but because i cannot update my version since there is no update button where it is supposed this is no solution for me. Unfortunately. Whole discussion about this over here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/ifs-and-switch-functions-missing-in-excel-in/64a05d07-7b4c-4a7f-a795-cb520807bb02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number use MATCH():

```
=MATCH(F2,{"Poor","Medium","High"},0)
```

This will return the requesite number you can combine with your existing formula like this:

```
=MATCH(VLOOKUP("Quality",INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&V2),2,FALSE),{"Poor","Medium","High"},0)
```